# Uploading textarea value directly to Dropbox

Tags: python, dropbox-api

Previous question was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173241/uploading-contents-of-a-textarea-to-dropbox#comment14658356_11173241, which obviously did me no good.

My new approach to this problem is to have my web interface interact with the python dropbox api.So I have the user run through the authentication steps , authenticate my app, etc. The part I'm having trouble with is having the contents of an html textarea be saved to dropbox as  an html file.

For example, the contents of the textarea will look something like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Page</title></head>
<body>
<p>This is some testing stuff</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to save the contents directly to dropbox as an html file? Or is there no way getting around having to save the contents to a file on the server first and then sending it to dropbox?

Comment: Dropbox hosts files, it won't create files. So you'll need to create a file and then you could indeed use the Dropbox API to store the file there.

Comment: If you have enough access to the server to connect to external sites and send HTTP requests, how hard can it be to write to a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`?

Comment: @katrielalex I was just trying to avoid using any extra server space. With enough use I don't believe creating a bunch of temp files everytime someone wanted to create a file would be very efficient. But you're right it wouldn't be hard at all to do that, I was just trying to get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the API at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api - the call you want is **files_put**.

There is no reason to write it to a file; you can construct the request directly. When the API asks for a filehandle, use a string stream instead.